# How to perform a quality check during kmllayer load

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using kmllayers from the standard Google Dev site:

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml'
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

How do you do error checking? In my example I have url with a get parameter to get a filtered response from a database whose return is a kml.

If I get a null response or a kml with no data, I want to redirect the page. How do I perform the check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation on KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer), the [KmlLayerStatus](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerStatus) can be retrieved from the KmlLayer:

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer,'status_changed', function() {
  if (ctaLayer.getStatus() != OK) {
     alert("error loading KML, status="+ctaLayer.getStatus());
  }
}
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```